# Ethernet connection drops after a few seconds

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have problems with my ethernet connection in Ubuntu 22.04.1. The connection drops afters a few seconds. The problem does not occur with the wireless.

Things I've tried:

- Disable IPV6
- Use static IP and fixed DNS
- Manage the interface without NetworkManager (via /etc/network/interfaces)
- Reboot router

but nothing works!

Info about interfaces:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller I225-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 02
       serial: xx:xx:xx:52:xx
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.15.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=1045:740 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:34 memory:fc600000-fc6fffff memory:fc700000-fc703fff memory:fc500000-fc5fffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 1a
       serial: ac:xx:xx:xx:xx:99
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-43-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode ip=192.168.5.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:32 memory:fc400000-fc403fff
```

Logs between activate wired connection and the connection drop (var/log/syslog).

https://pastebin.com/TVzDPHfD

UPDATE:
There are 2 weird things:

1. Ethernet connection comes and goes, it seems that it is negotiating something with the router... every 8 pings, there is one with long duration, it looks like a pattern. You can see ping duration here:
   https://pastebin.com/wE7CZ9r6
2. With Macbook laptop with ethernet, I can access the router web manager at 192.168.1.1. However with ubuntu in my browser I have an "192.168.1.1 refused to connect"...